# How can I calculate the azimuth from an earth station to a satellite

Tags: orbital-mechanics, low-earth-orbit

I have computed the ecef coordinates of both the user location on the ground, the satellite's ecef coordinates, as well as other inputs such as  altitude, lat, long of both satellite and earth station. I also am given other inputs such as satellite radius. I need to calculate azimuth and elevation. I know I can use online calculators but I'm writing a program and therefore need the formulas. I'm checking my work with this TLE element calculator https://www.satellite-calculations.com/TLETracker/SatTracker.htm

Comment: I know there are tons of equations online but they output values that don't match those in the TLE tracker.

Comment: You might try to extract the equations from the script on site: 
[tletracker.online.sat.calc](https://www.satellite-calculations.com/TLETracker/scripts/tletracker.online.sat.calc) - it's rather long and complex, but everything's in there. Start by finding `function calculate_lookangles` where the final values of azimuth and elevation are calculated, and work your way back from there - how it's called, with what parameters, and what functions generate these parameters.

Comment: Ok thank you. I just looked at the site and it looks great. I'm suprised I couldn't find it. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @JamesP at some point, if you decide that that has solved your problem, it's perfectly okay to write up a helpful answer to your own question and even accept it. That way future readers can benefit from your answer as well.

Comment: I agree. I found the process in the script a bit too long to follow and extract the equations into a complete answer, but once you have it, it would be great if you posted it as an answer to your question.

Comment: I went through it for hours and the results didn't match up with their own model. The source doesn't provide satisfactory explanations for the derivation of each value and there are certain errors such as confusing LST with GMST. Also it never specifies whether the site coordinates are in ECI or ECEF.

Comment: You might look into [CSPICE](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/). To find azimuth, you need more than just the positions. You also need the orientation of the Earth station (ie, which vector the station considers to be 'up', 'north', and 'east' at a given time [it changes as the Earth rotates]). You can get a reasonable approximation assuming a spherical Earth, but, for more precision, you'll want to compute the ["surface normal"](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/C/cspice/srfnrm_c.html)